# Edit Emmet default value

Tags: phpstorm, emmet

I would like to alter the default value of Emmet shortcut

**Example current behavior**

When I type `bgc` result is `background-color: #fff;`

**Desired behavior**

When I type `bgc` result required `background-color: red;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PhpStorm/WebStorm and other IDEA-based IDEs such standard Emmet templates are done via Live Templates functionality. Therefore:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Live Templates`
3. Locate `bgc` entry under `Zen CSS` group
4. Change the value after clicking `Edit variables` button (e.g. use your `red` or no value at all).

**NOTE:** Because you are changing from hex color code (`#fff`) to textual constant (`red`) you will also have to remove `#` symbol from actual template (the one with red/pink background on the screenshot below -- next to `$VAR0$` variable).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you time and effort. 
I was looking in wrong place under Editor > Emmet > CSS.

Comment: Thank you. It also help me using Intellij IDEA.